# time limit exceeded in python program

Tags: python-2.7

I am a beginner in the field of python coding.I am stuck with this code which I wrote as a solution for the problem -"ambiguous permutations" on codechef.It shows time limit exceeded when I run it on the website.Please help me with this issue.The code is given below:

```
type=[]
while(True):
    n = int(raw_input())
    def inverse_calculation(listhere=[]):
        listtwo =[]
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            a = listhere.index(i)
            listtwo.append((int(a)+1))
        if (listtwo == listhere):
            return type.append('ambiguous')
        else:
            return type.append('not ambiguous') 
    if (n!=0):
        list1 = []    
        list1 = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
        inverse_calculation(list1)
    else:
        break
for element in type:
    print(element)
```

Comment: When you test this code yourself, does it work properly?

Comment: Yes Tevemadar, it does.

Answer (score 0):

Here in the code your `n` value will always be not equal to zero ,that is, your `if` condition will always be `true`, come what may, because you are not decrementing or altering the value of `n` in you entire program. And since your while condition is always true you are bound to get this error.
So my suggestion is you try to alter the value of `n` in your program.